# How to get all users at once with a GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, strapi

### List 101 Users with GraphQL

Why I can not get **all users at once** while using PostGQL?

It just returns first 100 users while using GraphQL but works fine with a GET request.

#### GraphQL Query

[image: get users]

```json
    {
      users(limit: 101, sort: "username") {
        id
        username
      }
    }
```

#### Result

[image: result]

Using **Get Method** returns full set!

I can get the full data set by `GET /users?_limit=-1` if I use GET

**NOTE**: using `limit: -1` does not work either.

```json
{
  users(limit: -1) {
    id
    username
  }
}
```

---

- **Strapi Version**:3.4.1
- **Operating System**: Windows, Ubuntu
- **Database**: Mysql, PostgreSQL
- **Node Version**: 14.15.3
- **NPM Version**: 6.14.9
- **Yarn Version**: 1.22.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `amountLimit` for the GraphQL plugin is 100. You can change this limit as stated [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#configurations)